# Following is the code in .bat which is used to download files from server, unable to convert token to a string to extract substring from it

Tags: batch-file

**Problem**: unable to convert token to a string to extract substring from it
Following is the batch file used to download files from server([link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jk4wS.png)):

```
call epmautomate login %USERNAME% %PASSWORD% %URL% %IDENTITY_DOMAIN%
set FILENAME="outbox/logs"
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('epmautomate listfiles ^| findstr ^ %FILENAME%') do (
 call epmautomate downloadfile "%%i"
 rem THIS LINE THROWS "ECHO IS OFF"
 echo "%%i~5"
)
call epmautomate logout
```

I tried `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` too, but hard luck.

Comment: Set a variable to `%%i`, then expand the variable. You cannot expand `%%i` like that. You will probably find that you'll need to use delayed expansion in achieving that too. Now please re-visit your question, remove the link and post a copy of the batch file content as formatted code, which people can copy and test.

Comment: Can u please post modified lines of code that can give me better clarity, Thanks !!

Comment: setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
 echo "%%i"
 set name = "%%i"
 echo !name!    -- I tried expanding variable too like this, but hard luck :(

Comment: Please, read my previous comment, especially the last sentence!

Comment: `%%i` is NOT a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Stui as @Compo mentioned, you cannot manipulate the loop iteration outputs `%%a` as you can a variable `%var1%`.

Instead use `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` to allow you to get the current/most recent value of a variable from within the loop.

Set loop iteration output (`%%i`) to a variable (`%downloadfile%`) then manipulate that variable (`!downloadfile:~5!`) in your echo statement.

I haven't tried the below code, but hopefully it works for you.

```
call epmautomate login %USERNAME% %PASSWORD% %URL% %IDENTITY_DOMAIN%

set FILENAME="outbox/logs"

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('epmautomate listfiles ^| findstr ^ %FILENAME%') do (
    call epmautomate downloadfile "%%i"
    set "downloadfile=%%i"
    echo !downloadfile:~5!
)
endlocal

call epmautomate logout
```

Comment: **Thanks**, this works like a charm. Although when I tried it earlier, I was still not getting proper result using set file="%%i" instead of set "file=%%i", I am not sure if that has made all the difference !!!

Comment: With `set file="hello world"` it will store the value as `"hello world"` (Including the  quotation marks in the value of `%file%`).  If instead you use `set "file=hello world"` it will only store the value as `hello world` meaning that you do not need to manipulate the variable's string anywhere else such as `echo %file:"=%` to remove the quotation marks, yet still ensures you can store strings containing spaces.

Comment: Awww, Thanks for this explanation !!